# How to configure VS to build hlsl file multiple times with different defines (/D stuff)

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, directx, shader, hlsl

Recently I want to change my run-time shader compilation into build-time shader compilation by use vs built-in shader compiler (so you could right click on the hlsl file from vs solution explorer, and change the item type to HLSL compiler to use this built-time shader compilation thing, so every time you compile your project, the shader will be compiled, and you only need to load the compiled byte code in runtime). The problem I have is that most of my shaders files need to compiled to multiple versions (different macro define flags), it's very easy to do it during run-time (just compile, change define flag, and compile again), however I can't find any option in vs which allow you to compile the same hlsl file multiple times with different defines.

So I come here and ask you guys for help, suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple project configurations, and set up different preprocessor definitions for them in the HLSL Compiler/General settings.